# How to get the terminal started with user@hostname:$

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

When Opening a new terminal in Ubuntu the terminal just has $ symbol instead of user@hostname:$

After I type $bash in the terminal it switches to have the correct symbol of user@hostname:$

How to get the terminal started with user@hostname:$ ?

1) I use ctrl + alt + t to start the terminal.
2) No changes in bashrc so far.
3) I removed all files in ~/.gnome/ directory

Comment: Please add to your question what keys or mouse clicks you use to start the terminal the first time and also if you've made changes to `.bashrc`, deleted dot files, etc.

Comment: Edited the question to add the information

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/passwd file

I changed 
sajith:x:1001:1001::/home/sajith:/bin/sh
to
sajith:x:1001:1001::/home/sajith:/bin/bash

and rebooted the VM (maybe logout and login is sufficient.) Now When I open terminal it works as expected.

[image: as shown below]